# How to get an older version of a file using git?

Tags: git

Is there any way, using the git API, to programmatically get a list of versions of a specific file, and then get the contents of a specific one?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You can start with `rev-list` to get a reverse chronological (i.e. newest first) list of hashes where the file in question was modified:

```
git rev-list HEAD <filename>
```

You can then use `git show <hash>:<filepath>` to show a file's contents.

#### Show contents at every hash

I'm not sure if you want to see *every* version's contents, but you could loop through each with a simple `for` loop:

```sh
for hash in `git rev-list HEAD dummy_repo/file.c`
do
    git show $hash:dummy_repo/file.c
done
```

#### Commit selection

For more feedback on what each commit changes, try `git whatchanged <filename>` (you'll be able to see the hash, type of modification, as well as the commit message).

Try `git whatchanged -p <filename>` to see what changes the commit actually introduced in the file. When you have a hash you like, you can again use `git show <hash>:<filepath>` for the complete contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of versions of a specific file

```
git log --relative <<file_path>>
```

To get the contents of the file

```
git show <<commit_hash>>:<<file_path>>
```